# jQuery $.attr() issue with select (drop-downs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Seems simple enough, but it just isn't working.

I'm trying to grab a handful of custom data attributes from dynamically generated `<option>`s.

The options are generating correctly and their syntax is correct:

```
<option value="xml/airports/africa.xml" data-pos="5" data-airport="Noumérat - Moufdi Zakaria Airport">Noumérat - Moufdi Zakaria Airport</option>
```

However when I try to console log these values, I keep getting `undefined`.

The script for it is seemingly simple and short:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sel = $('select');  //its the only select on the page
sel.change(function() {
            //some variations I have tried:
          var n = sel.attr('data-airport');
          var f = sel.val());         //****this is pulling fine
          var i = sel.attr('data-pos');
          console.log(n, i);
          console.log(sel.attr('data-pos');
          console.log($(this).attr('data-pos');
          console.log($('select').attr('data-pos');
})
})
```

I've done the obligatory google search to no avail...great ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes are assigned to the `option` element not to the `select` element. In your case you are trying to fetch the attribute value from the `select` element `sel`.

Instead you need to find the selected option from the `select` element.

it should be

```
var opt = sel.find('option:selected')

var i = opt.attr('data-pos');
console.log(opt.data('pos');
console.log(opt.attr('data-pos');
```